# Am I using the right frameworks effectively?

Tags: node.js, project-structure, web-framework

I am working on a large scale application that has both a web portal and a mobile application so therefore I need to develop an API..

I have decided to go with the following structure:-

- Sailsjs (this will be the front end, everything inside the application itself)
- lumen (this will provide the oauth client and also a way for the application itself to authenticate)

The reason that I'm using Sailsjs is because it provides me with an MVC framework and also a way to allow for real time, which the web application side relies on heavily.

I don't really want or need the the Sailsjs application to communicate with the API (only to authenticate through oauth) and once that's over I will allow for the Sailsjs application to read/write to the database itself.

My main doubt is that Sailsjs is providing an API - something I will not be using at all! Therefore is it a waste to just use Sailsjs just for the MVC framework? Also can anyone see any downsides to this approach? My main theory behind this approach is that the mobile application is heavily dependant and splitting the two out means that if the web application goes down, at least the mobile application should still operate on the data that was last given to it.

Would a better approach be to keep the lumen as the API and then use something like nodejs and express to do the web application in?

Comment: I would rethink using sails to create your webservice too. One of the big advantages of using js on the back end is how easy it is to share your models across the front & back end.

Comment: @RubberDuck - I will still be using Sailsjs as a back end (technically) as it will read/write straight from the database rather than allowing the API the API is just an oauth server and acts as a way to get data to the app! Does this make sense?